# Why is my code unable to read from my current file directory?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been doing a data science project with some friends and i need to import a data set from a file that is currently stored within my machine default downloads directory, but the code i have been working on is written for a windows machine and the file path different from my own machine, thus i can't import the data set as im not sure how i can replace the code so that it works. I've attempted to correct the path myself but i can't seem to get it to read its location, even though i think the path is correct. Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import os, sys 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 
from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#DataFlair - Read the data
df= pd.read_csv('/home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data.') 
df.head()

#DataFlair - Get the features and labels
features=df.loc[:,df.columns!='status'].values[:,1:]
labels=df.loc[:,'status'].values

#DataFlair - Get the count of each label (0 and 1) in labels
print(labels[labels==1].shape[0], labels[labels==0].shape[0])

#DataFlair - Scale the features to between -1 and 1
scaler=MinMaxScaler((-1,1))
x=scaler.fit_transform(features)
y=labels

#DataFlair - Split the dataset
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)

#DataFlair - Train the model
model=XGBClassifier()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)

# DataFlair - Calculate the accuracy
y_pred=model.predict(x_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100)
```

I can't get the correct file path, i have entered what i think is the correct file path for the file, that being the default downloads directory on my user, as well as making sure that all of the characters are case sensitive.

Whenever i run the code i continue to get an error saying the following: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/morgankemp@pop-os/Home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data'"

Additional information is that I'm running Pop_OS and am using VSC. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: what the error? (and the question?)

Comment: Is the filename supposed to have a `.` at the end?  You wrote `'/home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data.'`

Comment: The error is the following: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/morgankemp@pop-os/Home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data' " 

And the question is that i don't really understand why im getting this error, the file is located within my default downloads directory, i have made sure that all of the cases are exactly the same as the path. My question is what am i doing wrong? I have never imported something on Linux so I'm not too sure if I'm doing something wrong with the files directory, or if I'm missing something.

Comment: `'/morgankemp@pop-os/Home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data'`  This isn't what you wrote in your question.  Though it's probably something you copied from the terminal.  If you want the path to your home directory try typing `pwd` in your shell.  Any other files in your home directory will be relative to that.

Comment: I don't know--the problem isn't that deep, you just aren't entering the path to the file correctly.  (To be clear, I know file paths can be tricky to get right for beginners, especially if they are not familiar with command line tools.)

Comment: You're quite right, I've since been trying other paths that i think might work, I'm also aware that the problem I'm having here is rather trivial, I know that the file is in my default directory, i thought that i wrote it out correctly but i guess i haven't. If i revert my code to how it was in the post and run it again i get this error: 

"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/morgankemp@pop-os/Home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data'" 

I know the file is in my downloads from this konsole input "morgankemp@pop-os:~$ ls /home/morgankemp/Downloads
parkinsons.data

Comment: I just figured it out, i forgot that when working on Unix systems the path starts with a slash, and i of course didn't include one. Well, you live and you learn, thank you for your comments and i understand that this was a rather trivial problem, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your file is 'parkinsons.data.csv'.

Replace

`df= pd.read_csv('/home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data.')`

With

```
df= pd.read_csv('/home/morgankemp/Downloads/parkinsons.data.csv')
```